# How to print the elements in the descending order of the frequency of each elements?

Tags: data-structures

> You are given an array with N elements (May not be distinct). Check
> frequency of each element and print the elements in descending order
> of frequency of each element.
>
> If two elements having same frequency then the bigger value will be
> print first.
>
> For Example:-
>
> N=5 ar[] = {1,2,2,1,6}
>
> Frequency of elements are :-   1 - 2 times 2 - 2 times 6 - 1 time
>
> Now print elements in descending order of frequency. Hence output is
> :- {2,1,6} As 2 is greater than 1 and both have same frequency so
> bigger value i.e 2 is print first.

I am not getting the optimize logic of the problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part do you have trouble with? Determining the frequencies? Getting the result array? Sorting the result array by frequency?

Comment: Store the frequency using a map (C++ STL), then traverse the map and copy it into a vector of pairs and then sort the vector using a custom comparator.

Comment: @risingStark according to you, I completed the copying to vectors of pairs but after that when I sort the vector, If I sort according to frequency in decreasing order then answer will be 1,2,6 which is not required. I need answer as 2,1,6

Comment: @abhishek kaushik You need to use sort function with modified compare function, such that for equal frequency case, it returns bigger number. Example: `sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const pair<int,int> a, const pair<int,int>b) { if(a.second == b.second) { return a.first > b.first;}else { return a.second > b.second; }});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sorting the vector according to descending order of frequency, I guess you have missed the equal frequency condition. Obviously normal sorting will preserve the natural order of duplicate elements in the frequency vector/list.

You are required to first check the equality of two frequencies. If equal then sort by their keys.

Example : `frequency list={3(2),3(1),3(5),1(9)}`
Then natural descending sort would be : `{2,1,5,9}` (or `{1,2,5,9}` depending on implementation).
But you require `{5,2,1,9}`.
Therefore, we will modify the sort function as below :

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const pair<int,int> a, const pair<int,int>b) { 
    if (a.second == b.second) { 
        return a.first > b.first;
    }else{
        return a.second > b.second; 
    }
});
```